# Programa basico c++ para devolver si un numero es mayor o menor a 10

Tags: c++

Hola recien arranco en c++ y quiero hacer un programa que tome un numero ingresado por el usuario a travez del teclado y devuelva si es igual, mayor o menor a 10, como para aprender como funciona el lenguaje. El problema es que lo habia logrado hasta que le quize agregar que no tome valores que no sean numeros, en cuyo caso aparezca un msj que diga que no es un numero, y ahora no me detecta correctamente cuando es mayor, cuando es menor o cuando no es un numero y entrevera todo, no se en que le estoy errando.

```
#include "iostream"
#include "conio.h"
#include "cstdlib"
#include "stdio.h"

using namespace std;


int main(){

    int numero;

    cout << "Vamos a evaluar si un numero es menor que 10 \n" << endl;
    cout << "Ingrese un numero por favor..." << endl;
    cin >> numero;

    if (isdigit(numero)) {
        if (numero < 10){
            cout << "El numero es menor que 10." << endl;
        }
        else if (numero == 10){
            cout << "El numero es 10." << endl;
        }
        else if (numero > 10){
            cout << "El numero es mayor que 10." << endl;
        }
    }

    else {
        cout << "Eso no es un numero!" << endl; 
    }   

    system ("pause");
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: tienes que marcar como correcto si una respuesta soluciono tus dudas

Answer (score 5, accepted):

isdigit toma como parámetro caracteres, no un entero, y a eso se debe el comportamiento erróneo. Deberías crear una nueva variable de tipo char para comprobar que lo ingresado por el usuario es un número, y luego, si lo es, castearlo y hacer tus comparaciones.

**Actualización**: incluyo un ejemplo de código para comprobar números hasta unidades de mil. Es básico, pero espero que te de una idea:

```
#include "iostream"
#include "conio.h"
#include "cstdlib"
#include "stdio.h"

using namespace std;

/*
    Se inicializa el arreglo de caracteres para evitar cualquier caracter extraño o basura en las posiciones de memoria que ocupa
*/
void InicializarArreglo(char digitos[], int limite)
{
    for (int indice = 0; indice < limite; indice++)
    {
        digitos[indice] = '\0';
    }
}

/*
    Se verifica que cada uno de los caracteres sea un digito válido. No acepta enteros negativos
*/
bool ComprobarDigitos(char digitos[], int limite)
{
    int indice = 0;
    bool esValido = true;   

    while (indice < limite && digitos[indice]!=0)
    {       
        if (!(isdigit(digitos[indice])))
        {
            esValido = false;
            break;
        }           

        indice++;
    }

    return esValido;
}

/*
    Devuelve la cantidad de posiciones que fueron ocupadas dentro del arreglo
*/
int PosicionesUtilizadas(char digitos[], int limite)
{
    int indice = 0;
    while (digitos[indice] != '\0' && indice<limite)
    {
        indice++;
    }

    return indice;
}

/*
    En base al numero de posiciones ocupadas, comienza con una base "1" para la unidad, luego se convierte en "10" para la decena, en "100" para la centena, etc.
    Y antes de multiplicar, si debe restar 48 porque el valor númerico de los caracteres es un entero que corresponde a un código ASCCI, en este caso, los digitos del 0 al 9
    tienen los codigos 48 al 57. El 0 es 48-48= 0. Para el 1 es 49-48= 1, etc.
*/
int ConvertirNumero(char digitos[], int limite)
{
    int numero = 0; 
    int posicionesUtilizadas = 0;
    posicionesUtilizadas = PosicionesUtilizadas(digitos, limite);
    int base = 1;

    for (int indice = posicionesUtilizadas-1; indice >= 0; indice--)
    {       
        numero = numero + ((digitos[indice] - 48)*base);
        base = base * 10;
    }

    return numero;

}



int main(){
    const int limite = 5;
    char arregloDigitos[limite];
    int numero;

    InicializarArreglo(arregloDigitos, limite);

    cout << "Vamos a evaluar si un numero es menor que 10 \n" << endl;
    cout << "Ingrese un numero por favor..." << endl;
    cin >> arregloDigitos;

    if (ComprobarDigitos(arregloDigitos, limite)) {

        numero = ConvertirNumero(arregloDigitos, limite );

        if (numero < 10){
            cout << "El numero es menor que 10." << endl;
        }
        else if (numero == 10){
            cout << "El numero es 10." << endl;
        }
        else if (numero > 10){
            cout << "El numero es mayor que 10." << endl;
        }
    }

    else {
        cout << "Eso no es un numero!" << endl;
    }

    system("pause");
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: hice lo que me dijiste y ahora por lo menos distingue un caracter de un numero corriente, pero todo los numeros me los toma como mayor de 10.
`código`
    char comprobar;
    int numero;
    cout << "Ingrese un numero por favor..." << endl;
    cin >> comprobar;
  
    if (isdigit(comprobar)) { 
    numero = comprobar;
    if (numero < 10){
    cout << "El numero es menor que 10." << endl;
    }
    else if (numero == 10){
    cout << "El numero es 10." << endl;
    }
    else if (numero > 10){
    cout << "El numero es mayor que 10." << endl;
    } 
    }

Comment: perdon por poner el codigo asi todavia no entiendo como poner el codigo en comentarios

Comment: Eso es porque en la conversión numero = comprobar, está tomando el código ASCII de comprobar. En la tabla ASCII, el número 1, por ejemplo, tiene el código 49 (y por eso te indica que siempre es mayor que 10). Entonces, en el código numero = comprobar, realmente lo esta tomando así: numero = 49. Si le restas 48 (que es el código equivalente a 0 en ASCII) obtendrás el número 1. Prueba así: numero = comprobar -48; El por qué entran los códigos ASCII aquí se debe a la conversión de char a int. Por ejemplo, int variable = 'A'; es válido porque se toma el código ASCII de 'A' que si es un entero.

Comment: Gracias por la actualizacion.... me va a servir para analizarlo....

Answer (score 0):

De acuerdo a la [documentación](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cctype/isdigit/):

> Checks whether c is a decimal digit character.
>
> Decimal digits are any of: 0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9

Si tu input es **10**, es posible que no sea reconocido como "dígito".

---

Usa otra forma de validar si el input es un número válido.

Answer (score 0):

podrias usar la funcion atoi  y validarlo con un do while desde el ascii del 0 a 9 entre comillas simple y si ingresas algun caracter o cadena t va a pedir que te ingreses de nuevo le podes poner un mensaje dentro del do while  se entendio?

Comment: Quizás la respuesta se beneficiaría con un fragmento de código. La idea es sumar respuestas completas con la mayor calidad posible